# T-SQL with inner join, group by, and timespan on result

Tags: sql-server, group-by, inner-join, datediff

I am joining two tables. The result will return two records for each person. One will have a record for "D" and then the "A" record.

From the 1st result, I need to get the time elapsed between the "D" and the "A" record and return the event, person, and elapsed time. So far I can only get to the 1st result returning the two records:

```
SELECT 
    a.eventID, qry1.person, qry1.transtype, qry1.timestamp  
FROM
    table1 a
INNER JOIN
    (SELECT 
         eventID, transtype, person, timestamp 
     FROM
         table2 b 
     WHERE
         b.transtype IN ('D','T','A')  
         AND EXISTS (SELECT person FROM table2 c 
                     WHERE c.transtype = 'A'  
                       AND c.eventID = b.eventID 
                       AND c.person = b.person)) qry1 ON a.eventID = qry1.eventID 
WHERE
    a.service = 'FIRE' 
    AND a.calltime >= GETDATE() - 365
    AND a.cancelled <> 1
ORDER BY 
    qry1.eventID, qry1.person, qry1.timestamp
```

This returns my first list:

```
eventID   person  transtyp   timestamp
----------------------------------------------------
101234    EA1       D        2016-10-07 10:12:58.853
101234    EA1       A        2016-10-07 10:15:31.537
101234    EA2       D        2016-10-07 10:13:51.841
101234    EA2       A        2016-10-07 10:18:31.438
101236    EA1       D        2016-10-07 10:11:58.554
101236    EA1       A        2016-10-07 10:13:31.631
```

Now from the above result, I need to get the elapsed time between
the D and the A record for each person on each event so it should return:

```
eventID   person  Elapsed Time
101234    EA1       0:02:32
101234    EA2       0:04:39
```

and this all needs to go into one tsql query.....

I can get the elapsed time using:

```
declare @minDate datetime = '2016-10-07 10:13:51.841'
declare @maxDate datetime = '2016-10-07 10:18:31.438'

-- Get timespan in hh:mi:ss
select cast(
(cast(cast(@maxDate as float) - cast(@minDate as float) as int) * 24) /* 
 hours over 24 */
    + datepart(hh, @maxDate - @minDate) /* hours */
    as varchar(10))
    + ':' + right('0' + cast(datepart(mi, @maxDate - @minDate) as 
    varchar(2)), 2) /* minutes */
    + ':' + right('0' + cast(datepart(ss, @maxDate - @minDate) as   
    varchar(2)), 2) /* seconds */
```

but cannot get into the original query to use against the 1st result.
I am having trouble selecting the correct timestamps for each person on each
event in the 1st result to use for computing the time elapsed into a
2nd result.

Ideas?

(Note:  I am only selecting those records that have an 'A' transtype record so I don't get a 'D' without an 'A'. )

Comment: Why the cast date as float? Is this a performance gain somehow? If you are on SQL Server 2012 or higher you can use LAG here I think.

Comment: Has to work with SQL2005 or later....

Comment: What if you use partition by in CTE and then join row 1 to row 2?

Comment: Good idea, I will play with that see and see...

Comment: Use like this way to select timestamps :  select `eventID`,  ` person` , min(timestamp),max(timestamp)  group by  `eventID`,  ` person`

Comment: That isn't working because there are other timestamp records with different transtypes like 'E', 'L' etc

Comment: OK, I have it working now (a combination of the partition and the min/max on timestamp.  However, I have discovered that there are occasionally multiple 'A' transtype records and I only want to capture the first 'A' record by timestamp.

Comment: Got that figured out too.  So all is good now.  Thanks all!